# Rcpp error with sugar all() line

Tags: c++, r, header, compiler-errors, rcpp

I've written some code for R with Rcpp and C++ to try and become more familiar with it:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
CharacterMatrix reduce_sequences(CharacterMatrix completeDNA)
{
  std::vector<int> informativeSites; 
  for(int i = 0; i < completeDNA.ncol(); i++)
  {
    CharacterVector bpsite(completeDNA.nrow());
    for(int n = 0; n < completeDNA.nrow(); n++)
    {
      bpsite[n] = completeDNA(n,i); 
    }
    if(any(bpsite != bpsite[0]).is_true()) informativeSites.push_back(i);
  }
  CharacterMatrix cutDNA(3, informativeSites.size());
  for(int i = 0; i < informativeSites.size(); i++)
  {
    for(int n = 0; n < cutDNA.nrow(); n++)
    {
      cutDNA(n,i) = completeDNA(n,informativeSites[i]);
    }
  }
  return cutDNA;
}
```

But I get a comple error but not from my source file, but from Comparator_With_One_Value.h:

I won't pretend to understand these errors fully because I'm still in my C++ infancy, but by commenting out my code suitably and finding what causes it, it is my line 17:

```
if(any(bpsite != bpsite[0]).is_true()) informativeSites.push_back(i);
```

I think it has to do with me using any(). What is it I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: Changed the lines to reflect all issues above resolved except two:
Console output:

```
Error in Rcpp::sourceCpp("reduceseq.cpp") : 
  Error 1 occurred building shared library.
```

Issues returned from Comparator_With_One_Value.h
`operands to ?: have different types 'SEXPREC*' and 'int'`
and
`invalid conversion from 'SEXPREC* const' to 'int'`

Thanks,
Ben.

Answer (score 2):

We prevent this on purpose because of the 3 values logical in `R`: `TRUE`, `FALSE`, `NA`. You should be able to use `is_true` like this :

```
if(any(bpsite != bpsite[0]).is_true()) informativeSites.push_back(i);
```

Comment: Hi, this get's rid of the issue but there are two others remaining in the errors output. These are in Comparitor_With_One_Value.h and are still caused by this line - if I remove comment the errors stop. `Operands to ?; have different types 'SEXPREC*' and "int"` and `invalid conversion from "SEXPREC* const" to "int".`. It seems to think in that line I'm converting a SEXP to an integer, but the datatypes used on that line are std::vector, and a `CharacterVector`. `i` which get's pushed back onto `std::vector<int>` is also `int` unless I'm mistaken (probably!).

Comment: I just answered this on rcpp-devel as well as I had not seen your question here.  *Please pick one*, the list or SO, but do *not cross-post*.  We usually recommend rcpp-devel, but it is your choice.